# Spring Integration: Lower core pool size on task executor

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using spring integration to perform parallel processing on channel outputs. I have a requirement that the amount of parallelism that goes on needs to be controllable - so I need to be able to increase it or to lower it. Here is my current set up:

```
<service-activator input-channel="computerInputChannel" ref="computer" method="compute">
  <poller task-executor="computerRequestExecutor" fixed-rate="1000"></poller>
</service-activator>

<task:executor id="computerRequestExecutor" pool-size="1" queue-capacity="100" />
<channel id="computerInputChannel"><queue/></channel>
```

and in code, when I want to change the amount of parallelism, I run the setCorePoolSize method.

My problem is that when I increase the core pool size, I get increased parallelism, but when I then decrease the core pool size, the increased parallelism doesn't go away. For example, if the core pool size is set initially to 1, I see the tasks run one at a time. And if it is then set to 5 I see them run 5 at a time. But if I reset it to 1, they'll continue to run 5 at a time.

How can I throttle the parallelism?

I can follow the code and see that interruptIfIdle() is being called from the ThreadPoolExecutor class, but nothing ever comes from that.

I am very new to spring integration and may be approaching this from the wrong angle. Any help or alternate suggestions for how to achieve what I want would be great.

[This post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?109045-Reducing-the-thread-pool-for-ServiceActivator-s-taskexecutor) is pretty much my exact question if what I wrote was unclear - unfortunately it was never answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received an answer from the [spring integration forums](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?135197-Llowering-core-pool-size-on-task-executor-does-nothing)

Basically I needed to ensure the task executor had a queue size of 0, that the keep alive time was 0, and that the max-messages-per-poll on the poller was 1.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think you actually want to be changing the maxPoolSize. If the core grows, max also grows such that the following condition is always true: max >= core

If core is 1 and max is 5, then given idle time/task-limit settings are also configured, the pool can shrink down from the max to the core size.

Hope that helps.

Comment: No that doesn't do it. I have tried decreasing both to no effect.

Comment: including idle time/task-limit settings?... there's a bit more detail on the reply in the SpringSource forum - last post by Gary (I assume that is your question there as well?):  http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?135197-Llowering-core-pool-size-on-task-executor-does-nothing